# How to set Y axis range when using multiple graphs in Coreplot

Tags: iphone, graph, range, core-plot

I'm using coreplot for plotting two graphs in one view. The data that is being plotted changes when a user choses to receive different kinds of data.

The data I receive is being plotted properly. However I'd like to change the range of one of the Y axis when it needs to. (The data could differ from 0 to 40 or from 0.0 to 1.0).

How can I implement this function so that when a user plots data from 0.0 to 1.0 the y-axis it's range also changes to these values

Here's a snippit of my code:

```
- (void)renderInLayer:(CPTGraphHostingView *)layerHostingView withTheme:(CPTTheme *)theme fromGraph:(int)graphNumber
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    CGRect bounds = layerHostingView.bounds;
layerHostingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Create the graph and assign the hosting view.
    graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    layerHostingView.hostedGraph = graph;

    [graph applyTheme:theme];
    graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];

    graph.plotAreaFrame.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
    graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil; 

    graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;

    // chang the chart layer orders so the axis line is on top of the bar in the chart.
    NSArray *chartLayers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypePlots],
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeMajorGridLines], 
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeMinorGridLines],  
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisLines], 
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisLabels], 
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisTitles], 
                                                            nil];
graph.topDownLayerOrder = chartLayers;    
    [chartLayers release];

// Add plot space for horizontal bar charts
    graph.paddingLeft = 45.0;
    graph.paddingTop = 40.0;
    graph.paddingRight = 45.0;
    graph.paddingBottom = 60.0;

 // Setup plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
    plotSpace.delegate = self;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(28.0f)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(45)];

    CPTScatterPlot *highPlot2 = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
    highPlot2.identifier = @"Graph2";

CPTMutableLineStyle *highLineStyle2 = [[highPlot2.dataLineStyle mutableCopy] autorelease];
    highLineStyle2.lineWidth = 1.f;
    highLineStyle2.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.00f green:0.00f blue:0.00f alpha:0.0f];
    highPlot2.dataLineStyle = highLineStyle2;
    highPlot2.dataSource = self;

CPTFill *areaFill2 = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.00f green:0.92f blue:0.0f alpha:0.58f]];
    highPlot2.areaFill = areaFill2;
    highPlot2.shadow = Shadow;
    highPlot2.areaBaseValue = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
    [graph addPlot:highPlot2];

// Setup grid line style
    CPTMutableLineStyle *majorXGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    majorXGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    majorXGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.60f];
CPTMutableTextStyle *TextStyleBlack = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    TextStyleBlack.color     = [CPTColor blackColor];
    TextStyleBlack.fontSize  = 15.0;

// Setup x-Axis.
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    x.majorGridLineStyle = majorXGridLineStyle;
    x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(@"1");
    x.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;

    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
    x.title = @"Days";
    x.timeOffset = 30.0f;
    NSArray *exclusionRanges = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(0)], nil];
    x.labelExclusionRanges = exclusionRanges;

    NSMutableArray *labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[sampleDays count]];

    int idx = 0;
    for (NSString *day in sampleDays)
    {
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:day textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
        label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromInt(idx);
        label.offset = 5.0f;
        [labels addObject:label];
        [label release];
        idx++;
    }
    x.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:labels];
    [labels release];

// Setup y-Axis.
    CPTMutableLineStyle *majorYGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    majorYGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
majorYGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.60];
CPTXYAxis *y1 = axisSet.yAxis;
    y1.majorIntervalLength = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10"]decimalValue];
    y1.labelShadow = Shadow;
    y1.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
    y1.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
    y1.labelTextStyle = TextStyleYellow;
    y1.labelOffset = 15;
    y1.axisLineStyle = nil;
NSArray *yExlusionRanges = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0)],
                                nil];
    y1.labelExclusionRanges = yExlusionRanges;

//setup second y axis
CPTXYAxis *y2 = [[(CPTXYAxis *)[CPTXYAxis alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
y2.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    y2.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"27");
    y2.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
    y2.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 4;
    y2.majorGridLineStyle = majorYGridLineStyle;
 y2.labelOffset = - 40.0;    
    y2.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
    y2.plotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    y2.majorIntervalLength = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10"]decimalValue];
y2.minorTickLineStyle = nil;
y2.axisLineStyle = nil;

//add all axis to the graph
graph.axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y1, y2,nil];

// Create a high plot area
    CPTScatterPlot *highPlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
    highPlot.identifier = kHighPlot;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *highLineStyle = [[highPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy] autorelease];
    highLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.f;
    highLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.00f green:0.00f blue:0.00f alpha:0.0f];
    highPlot.dataLineStyle = highLineStyle;
    highPlot.dataSource = self;

    //fillcolor
    CPTFill *areaFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:1.00f green:0.97f blue:0.0f alpha:0.41f]];
    highPlot.areaFill = areaFill;
    highPlot.shadow = Shadow;
    highPlot.areaBaseValue = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
    [graph addPlot:highPlot];

// Create the Savings Marker Plot
    selectedCoordination = 2;

    touchPlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull] autorelease];
    touchPlot.identifier = kLinePlot;

    touchPlot.dataSource = self;
    touchPlot.delegate = self;

    [self applyTouchPlotColor];

    [graph addPlot:touchPlot];

    [pool drain];

}
```

### EDIT:

The solution came out to:
A. remove the graph.defaultPlotSpace before initializing the plotspaces.
B. adding both plotspaces

```
[graph addPlotSpace:plotSpace2];
[graph addPlotSpace:plotSpace];
```

C. asign both plots to it's own plotspace

```
[graph addPlot:highPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
[graph addPlot:highPlot2 toPlotSpace:plotSpace2];
```

Answer (score 0):

The plot ranges are part of the plot space. Just update the `yRange` whenever you want to change the displayed range. You can do this any time, not just when setting up the graph.

Comment: When I change the yRange or xRange then both of my y axes changes into these parameters. even if I declare two of them with CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
create plotspace1 and CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace; // create plotspace two and asign them to the specific axis with y1.plotSpace = plotSpace; and y2.plotSpace = plotSpace2; any other options?

Comment: `defaultPlotSpace` will always return the same plot space--it doesn't create a new one. You can alloc/init a new one and add it to the graph using `[graph addPlotSpace:plotSpace2];`.

Comment: The axis reacts fine when I'm using (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace; and asign it to the y axis. However the plot itself doesn't change. When I alloc and init the CPTXYPlotspace and asign it to the axis and plot all the labels then the labels are positioned to the down left corner and no plot is shown. Think I'm almost there. Any suggestions?

Comment: @BarryK88 I am facing the same problem right now. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: According to the maximum width of the label on the y-axis you need to set the padding of the axis.